# Accessing intermediate results in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following code and I think one would like to use pipes, but I cant figure out how - I have tried a ton of different approaches, but it appears I am missing a key understanding how piping works. Anyways: The following code does what I want it to:

project has_many budget_itens/work_items

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    project = Clients.get_project!(id)
    project = Map.put_new(project, :budget, total_budget(project.budget_items))
    project = Map.put_new(project, :budget_used, budget_used(project.work_items))
    project = Map.put_new(project, :budget_remaining, project.budget - project.budget_used)

    changeset = Clients.change_budget_item(%BudgetItem{project_id: project.id})
    render(conn, "show.html", project: project, changeset: changeset)
  end
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe operator [`|>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#%7C%3E/2), accoring to the documentation, does

> introduce the expression on the left-hand side as the first argument to the function call on the right-hand side.

That said, `project` construction might be done as

```rb
project = Clients.get_project!(id)

total = total_budget(project.budget_items)
used = budget_used(project.work_items)

project =
  project
  |> Map.put_new(:budget, total)
  |> Map.put_new(:budget_used, used)
  |> Map.put_new(:budget_remaining, total - used)
```